# Не выводиться ArraylLst java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, база-данных, arraylist

Не пойму почему не выводиться ArrayList.

Stats class

```
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler();

        Message scanner = update.getMessage();
        this.scanner = scanner;

        if (scanner != null && scanner.hasText()) {
            switch (scanner.getText()){
                case "/start":
                    Long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();
                    this.chatId = chatId;
                    databaseHandler.recordChatId(chatId);
                    System.out.println(chatId);
                    sendMsg(update.getMessage(), "Введите Тэг");
                    break;
                case "admins":
                    if (update.getMessage().getChatId() == Const.TG_ADMIN_PANEL){
                        sendMsg(update.getMessage(),  "Вы вошли в админку");
                        DatabaseHandler.listclass listclass = new DatabaseHandler.listclass();
                        List<DatabaseHandler.test> arrayList = listclass.listChatId();
                        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
                            System.out.println(i);
                        }
                    } else sendMsg(update.getMessage(), "Вы не админ");

                    break;
                default:
                    member(update);
            }

        }
```

Database class

```
Import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DatabaseHandler extends Configs {

    static class test {
        private int id;
        private int chatid;

        int getChatid() {
            return chatid;
        }

        void setChatid(int chatid) {
            this.chatid = chatid;
        }

        int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        void setId(int id) {
            this.id= id;
        }
    }

    static Connection dbconnection;

    public Connection getDbconnection() throws SQLException {
        String conectionString = dbURL + dbName;

        dbconnection = DriverManager.getConnection(conectionString, dbUsername, dbPass);
        return dbconnection;
    }

    public static class listclass {
        public ArrayList<test> listChatId() {

            ArrayList<test> table = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
                Statement Stmt = dbconnection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = Stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    test test = new test();
                    test.setChatid(resultSet.getInt(2));
                    test.setId(resultSet.getInt(1));
                }
            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                throwables.printStackTrace();
            }
            return table;
        }
    }


}
```

[image: Настройки полей]
[image: БД с данными]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayList не заполняется, поэтому остается пустым, нужно в метод `listChartId()` добавить одну строку, которая отмечена ниже

```
public ArrayList<test> listChatId() {

            ArrayList<test> table = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
                Statement Stmt = dbconnection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = Stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    test test = new test();
                    test.setChatid(resultSet.getInt(2));
                    test.setId(resultSet.getInt(1));

                    table.add(test);        // эта строка добавлена

                }
            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                throwables.printStackTrace();
            }
            return table;
}
```

Поправить цикл в методе `onUpdateReceived()` на

```
for (DatabaseHandler.test item : arrayList) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

А также добавить метод `toString()` в класс `test`, например такой

```
public String toString() {
    return "id = " + id + ", chatid" = chatid;
}
```

Comment: Упустил этот момент! Но проблема стала другой выводиться теперь числа 0 и 1

Comment: Вы правильно заметили, у вас выводилась позиция в ArrayList, внес дополнения в ответ